The link is broken when I click “Enter this room” in “Chat Event Reminder” in my inbox
When I click the enter this room link in the “chat.meta.stackexchange.com - Chat Event Reminder” inbox (in Gmail, not the Stack Exchange inbox),



it leads me to an error page: (the link)



Why that link brings me to this weird page, not transcript or enter the chat room?
There’s a sentence in the error page, that is:

Occasionally, messages or rooms may be removed for reasons of moderation: spam, off topic, abuse, etcetera.

But, I don’t think the room is removed, and I can see the transcript from the Stack Exchange inbox here.
Like what @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog says, the email link is incorrectly inserting a plus sign before the room ID. So, I hope the community can fix the link.

The email link is incorrectly inserting a plus sign before the room ID.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog You are correct, I edit the question by adding the link.
